# How do I use an ActiveSupport Concern to add a refinement to a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a concern that adds some helper methods to the including class. How can I automatically add a refinement to the including class?

The following example works, however, I'd like not explicitly have to state `using MyConcern` in `MyClass`

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class_methods do
    def test_method
      '1'
    end
  end
  refine String do
    def refined_method
      self
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyConcern
  using MyConcern
  def self.my_method
    test_method.refined_method
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like there is no way around that. According to the source code using can not be called from a method so it needs to be called from within the class.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I was following a reference in http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby which suggested using the `self.used` hook - but it appears that proposal was rejected (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11525)